# Mode of operation are availables with Camellia

Tags: encryption, tls, cipher-selection

What cipher mode of operation are available using [Camellia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_(cipher)) in a SSL certificate context ?

I'm mostly interested if XEX (Xor-Encrypt-Xor) or related mode (LRW, XTS...) can be used because they seem simple and very secure, if not implemented I would like to know why ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation

Answer (score 1):

## No. CBC and GCM only.

IANA maintains a [list of all official TLS/SSL cipher suites](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml).

And they list two RFCs for definitions of Camellia cipher suites:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5932, Only CBC.
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6367, Some CBC, some GCM.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine all supported ciphers as:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v | grep Camellia
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
CAMELLIA256-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
CAMELLIA128-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation, I speak about CBC, ECB, GCM, I didn't see anything related to that in your response

Comment: If you use tls, you don't get to decide this. You only get the mac-then-encrypt CBC defined in the RFC. If you control both endpoints, you can use a custom cipher suite.

Comment: @Z.T. In TLS1.2 (and soon 1.3?) you also get AEAD using GCM or CCM (both CTR-based) or ChaCha20-Poly1305 (stream). In particular there are Camellia+GCM suites in RFC6367, although not implemented by OpenSSL nor AFAICT Windows Schannel and MozillaNSS (Firefox).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I didn't know about camellia+gcm. I don't expect it to be deployed. I expect deployments to converge on supporting only aesgcm or chachapoly, depending on presence of hardware acceleration for aesgcm.